# ASP.Net default route doesn't return session cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I don't have a full reproduction scenario here as this has been happening in a large existing codebase; but my hope is that this will be explainable and someone will recognize the behaviour.

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application that uses Convention-Based routing, and along with a number of explicit routes it has the usual default Home/Index route. The default route has a strange behaviour in that it doesn't return an ASP.Net session cookie on first-request. If you reload the page or hit the same route without clearing cache/cookies; the session cookie is returned and set.

Default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The problem with this is we have anti-forgery tokens in place, and this scenario causes them to break on initial request (first page load, subsequent POST will fail). Additionally it seems to also affect the use of RequireHttpsAttribute on the Home/Index controller; in that it bypasses it and allows serving an insecure page on first-request as well.

Adding the following explicit route (above the default in order) fixes the issue:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Home",
   "",
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

**Update:** I might be explaining the "return" of the cookie incorrectly. What I mean is the result of the initial request to the default route in this scenario doesn't result in a cookie being established for this user. This is not the only behaviour happening but it seems to be a hint at what might be going on. At least it would be useful to know if there are any inherent differences between the full call stack/outcomes of a request that falls through to a default route vs an explicit one; if there are any at all.

Comment: Please add the code that creates the cookie. Most likely, this is due to the fact that you cannot create a cookie and read it again in a single HTTP request. You can only read it in subsequent requests. It has nothing at all to do with routing or even with MVC. But it would also help to know if you are actually writing the cookies to the response and reading them from the request objects (many people screw that up). See [How to: Write a Cookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx) and [How to: Read a Cookie](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd70eh18.aspx).

Comment: I'm not manually creating the cookie. It's a request verification cookie from use of the anti forgery token. The token is rendered on the page as expected, but the required cookie was not sent to match it on the initial request. So on subsequent post, an error is thrown by the framework for the token not matching the cookie. Additionally, the session cookie from ASP.Net that is returned on requests with explicit routes, not default initial, is the only difference I see when RequireHttps fails to redirect to https.